# Typescript literal string & union type matches both interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create typings for API responses, and based on the `error` property, the details of the API response changes.

I have these types:

```
export interface ResponseErrorUnknown {
  code: number;
  error: string & {};
  message: string;
  details: any;
}

export interface ResponseErrorFailedValidators extends ResponseError {
  error: 'failedValidators';
  details: {
    errors: Array<{
      field: string;
      validator: string;
    }>;
  }
}

export type ResponseError = ResponseErrorFailedValidators | ResponseErrorUnknown;
```

Now, when I get an API error, and it's a `failedValidators` error, I want my IDE to known that the `details` property are formatted like the interface `ResponseErrorFailedValidators`.

So like this:

```
if (apiError.error === 'failedValidators') {
  // apiError.details.errors should come up as a suggestion
} else {
  // apiError.details can be anything, because it matched the ResponseErrorUnknown
}
```

I've searched the internet looking for union and literal documentation of Typescript, but couldn't find what I was looking for. So I'm hoping for the best!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far I see you would like to being able to type check following code

```
  if (apiError.error === 'failedValidators') {
   // apiError.details.errors should come up as a suggestion
  } else {
   // apiError.details can be anything, because it matched the ResponseErrorUnknown
  }
```

so that withing condition block.

```
if (apiError.error === 'failedValidators') {
```

Typescript infers `apiError` as `ResponseErrorFailedValidators`

I'd would suggest using User-Defined Type Guards [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

In your case solution would be to define your custom type guard

```
const apiError: any = {
 error: "failedValidators",
 details: {
  errors: [],
 },
};

function isFailedValidator(
 unknowError: any
): unknowError is ResponseErrorFailedValidators {
  if ("error" in unknowError) {
   return unknowError.error === "failedValidators";
  }

  return false;
}

if (isFailedValidator(apiError)) {
 // apiError.details.errors should come up as a suggestion
 apiError.details
} else {
 // apiError.details can be anything, because it matched the ResponseErrorUnknown
}
```

In order to fully understand how this works, you need to understand `is` operator. As you can see the body of a function is essentially a predicate, return `true` or `false`. If it returns `true` then the value passed as the argument is of some type you have declared.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this is not the only error type I'll make. So in that case, I've to create those functions for every error type. That defeats the purpose, because in that case, I can just type the error after the `if` statement like `(apiError as ResponseErrorFailedValidators).details.errors`.

It'd be much better / simpler if there was a way the IDE does this automatically. But I didn't know about the User-Defined Type Guards, so thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @BartVersluijs you should be very cautious when using `as`. Avoid it as much as possible because you essentially break type inference data flow for your app and this can lead to unexpected runtime errors. It's a very rare occasion when it's eligible to use `as` if you use them too much it's essentially a code smell and you cannot rely on TS doing it's work properly

Comment: I'll definitely look into that. But I'm wondering, how do you cast an `unknown` type to the right type that you're sure it's a `string` for example? I've read that using `any` is no good and it's better to use `unknown`. But how can I cast this without using `as`? Create a new variable like `const stringVariable: string = unknownVariable;` or something?

Comment: @BartVersluijs it's not casting it's `type declaration`. You understand the difference between `type assertion` and `type declaration`. The thing like `const someVar: unknown = "someSTring"` is a type declaration. You can assign string to `unknown` because `unknown` is a top type, one of to be precise.